# Setting headers for ajax call giving error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, curl, http-headers

I am using an api service to get data from their website, for now, my PHP application using CURL to get data, it is working with out any issue. Now I want to get same data using jquery AJAX, I am trying my level best to get it done,[By the way, I am running this scripts from my localhost] but I am getting a 401 (Unauthorized) error, I am using same credential in header, below is how I am using headers for CURL:

```
$headers = array();
$headers[] = "Accept: application/abcd.zyxcomp+json";
$headers[] = "Key: abcd-efg-hijk-lmnoper";
$headers[] = "Authorization: Basic adsfas344yuyuyasdfasdvioasiovoiia=";
$headers[] = "Some-special-key: ourownauth";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
```

but when I try the above headers in jquery as below, I am getting 401 (Unauthorized) error.

```
$.ajax({
    url: apiURL,
    type: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/abcd.zyxcomp+json',
        'Authorization': 'Basic adsfas344yuyuyasdfasdvioasiovoiia=',
        'Key': 'abcd-efg-hijk-lmnoper',
        'Some-special-key': 'ourownauth'
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (result) {
        console.log(result, 'Success');
    },
    error: function (error) {
        console.log(error, 'Ooooops');
    }
});
```

Is there anything going wrong with my code? I could not find what is going on, I can see these errors logging in the console, please see the attachment.

[image]

Comment: Are you running your cURL request from the same IP address as where your browser is running the AJAX request? If not, could it be that they have IP whitelisting in place that allows your "server" to make the cURL request, while blocking your browser?

Comment: actually, I am testing on my localhost, is that a problem?? I have attached a screenshot of chrome console, please check my question.

Comment: The question is whether the API that you are hitting will be seeing your working cURL and failing AJAX requests as coming from the same IP address. If yes, then the IP address clearly isn't the problem. If no, then it might be, and you could perhaps try the cURL request from that same IP address to further test this theory. If you don't know, then I don't know what to say.